# When I redirect after submit, I get a blank page

Tags: php, header, submit

I'm learning PHP and MySQL. I need this form to redirect after submit, but it just goes to blank page. Here's my code:

```
<?php
$myFile = "teste.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
$stringData = $_POST ["email"];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = $_POST ["pass"];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
header("Location: sucess.htm");
exit;
?>
```

Comment: show us what is in `sucess.htm` ?

Comment: Turn on all error reporting at the start of your page - I suspect you've already send some output to the browser, possibly accidentally. This will prevent the `header()` call from being sent.

Answer (score 0):

There is a space between $_POST and the [ symbol. PHP will not execute code with syntax errors.